# Space-time white noise on PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Suppose I want to solve the following PDE
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \alpha \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = f(z,t) u+g(z,t)\int_{0}^{t}e^{\beta(s-t)}\xi(z,s)ds
\end{equation}
where $\xi(z,t)$ is a white noise process in space and time obeying the following properties
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[\xi(z,t) \right] = 0;\quad \mathbb{E}\left[\xi(z,t)\xi(z',t') \right] = \delta(z-z')\delta(t-t'),
\end{equation}
and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary constants. The function $u(z,t)$ is complex-valued and obeys the following conditions
\begin{equation}
u(z,0) = 0;\quad u(L,t) =u_0(t),
\end{equation}
We can obtain the expectation of $u$ by using
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \alpha\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\mathbb{E}[u] = f(z,t)\mathbb{E}[u]
\end{equation}
since the integral on the right vanishes when you apply the expectation operator. However, I am more interested in the variance of $u(z,t)$, which requires me to calculate $\mathbb{E}[u^2]$. We may attempt a solution by multiplying both sides by $u$, and using the chain rule on the left to obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z} + \alpha \frac{\partial }{\partial t}\right)\mathbb{E}[u^2] = f(z,t)\mathbb{E}[u^2]+g(z,t)\mathbb{E}\left[u\int_{0}^{t}e^{\beta(s-t)}\xi(z,s)ds\right],
\end{equation}
But now I run into the problem with the expectation on the RHS. Both $u$ and $\xi(z,t)$ are stochastic processes, so to find $\mathbb{E}\left[u\int_{0}^{t}e^{\beta(s-t)}\xi(z,s)ds\right]$ we would require an extra equation. Is there any other way to obtain $\mathbb{E}[u^2]$?

Comment: You can probably solve the PDE for a given realization of the noise by Fourier transforming over $x$. This will give you an ODE driven by a typical "time only" gaussian white noise. After solving the Fourier-space ODE and inverting this transform, you'll have $u$ for a given realization of the noise. You can then multiply $u$ by itself and apply the correlation function of $\langle \xi(z,s)\xi(y,t) \rangle$ to obtain the expectation value you seek. Incidentally, you say your technique needs an extra equation. This is true. Google the Furusku-Novikov formula.